# How to move all the artifacts from one artifact repository to another

Tags: maven, artifactory, artifact

I have code getting dependencies in pom.xml such as this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>thirdparty</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This artifact comes from a custom remote maven repository. We are trying to move all the artifacts under this groupId 'thirdparty' to go to the JFrog artifactory. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have all the Artifacts in a local Maven cache, you can upload them to the server hosting Artifactory and use the [import repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting#ImportingandExporting-Import) capability in order to import them into a given repository.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it is enough to just proxy the remote repository in your Artifactory. It will download and cache all the artifacts that are actually requested.

Otherwise you will probably have to write a custom script.

Comment: What do you mean when you talk about a custom script? Get all the artifacts to your local .m2 repository and upload them again to the artifactory ?

Comment: Something like that.